# AWS live upload video in chunks to S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a React web application that has a video recording feature (with react-media-recorder) where the user is able to record a video with his webcam. I am storing all my files in AWS. The problem is that now the video has a max length cause cloudflare doesnt allow bigger files to be transported from the frontend. I would like to implement a video streaming arhitecture to my web app with AWS, so the video is being live uploaded there in small chunks and then composed to an mp4 files at the end. What services should I use and how? I heard about Cloudfront and Lambda but I am not very familiar how they work.

Comment: could you find any solution?